# Creating year / month / day folder structure with Python in FTP

Tags: python, linux, ftp, ftplib

I'm looking for the option to create a year / month / day folder structure with the Python ftplib module

Connection:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_servidor, ftp_usuario, ftp_clave)
```

Loading variables:

```
ftp_raiz = 'TEST/'
filename = '2019-10-01T00-00-00.txt'
```

Function:

```
def cdTree(ftp, filename=None, path=None):

    if filename is not None:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename, '%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.txt')
        path = ftp_raiz + date.strftime('%Y') + '/' + date.strftime('%m') + '/' + date.strftime('%d')
        print filename
    if path != "":
        try:
            ftp.cwd(path)
        except error_perm as e:
            print e, ", creating folder"
            print path
            cdTree(ftp, path="/".join(path.split("/")[:-1]))
            ftp.mkd(path)
            ftp.cwd(path)

cdTree(ftp, filename, 'TEST')
```

Finally I do not create the folder structure, and it throws me the following error:

```
2018-10-18T00-00-00.txt
550 Failed to change directory. , creating folder
2018/10/18
550 Failed to change directory. , creating folder
2018/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp2.py", line 34, in <module>
    cdTree(ftp, filename)
  File "ftp2.py", line 30, in cdTree
    cdTree(ftp, path="/".join(path.split("/")[:-1]) )
  File "ftp2.py", line 31, in cdTree
    ftp.mkd(path)
  File "C:\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 589, in mkd
    resp = self.sendcmd('MKD ' + dirname)
  File "C:\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 251, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 226, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Create directory operation failed.
```

**Note:** perform the test of creating only one folder and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not make much sense to me.

I believe you wanted this:

```
def cdTree(ftp, path):
    print "entering folder {0}".format(path)
    try:
        ftp.cwd(path)
    except:
        print "failed to enter, creating"
        cdTree(ftp, path="/".join(path.split("/")[:-1]))
        ftp.mkd(path)
        ftp.cwd(path)

ftp_raiz = 'TEST/'
filename = '2019-10-01T00-00-00.txt'

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename, '%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.txt')
path = ftp_raiz + date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

cdTree(ftp, path)
```

Comment: The idea is to generate a folder structure according to date, your code works correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps but tried the same on HDFS file system and it helped me solve my requirement.One can change the required output in the function generateDateFromThisYear()

```
import datetime as d
import subprocess

def run_cmd(args_list):
    """
    run linux commands
    """
    # import subprocess
    print('Running system command: {0}'.format(' '.join(args_list)))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
    s_return = proc.returncode
    return s_return, s_output, s_err

def hdfsMakedir(hdfs_file_path):
    (ret, out, err) = run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-mkdir','-p', hdfs_file_path])



def make_necessary_dirs(dir_to_create: str):
    # print(pathExists(dir_to_create))
    if pathExists(dir_to_create) == 1:
        hdfsMakedir(dir_to_create)
        return dir_to_create
    else:
        return "the folder already exists"


list_of_dates =[]

def generateDateFromThisYear(year) :    

    months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    dt = "" #str(d.date(2012, 1, 1))
    for month in months:
        no_of_days = monthrange(year, month)[1] # Taking only second Value as it returns number of weeks and no of days 
        for day in range(1,no_of_days+1) :
            x = d.date(year,month,day)
            y= x.strftime("%Y")+'/'+x.strftime("%m")+'/'+x.strftime("%d")
            list_of_dates.append(y)

    for i in list_of_dates:
        make_necessary_dirs(i)
```